# How to store usage and memory percentage that are shown after login in AWS EC2

Tags: ubuntu, shell, aws, amazon-ec2

[ec2 stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUvIV.png)

when we ssh into our instance we can see these stats displaying. Is there any way to get the same percentage stats with a terminal command?

Answer (score 2):

You might have to script something. To get these values, you can use these commands:

```
cat /proc/loadavg # System load.
df -h # Free disk space on / (also in %).
free -h # Free memory. You have to calculate the % yourself
grep Swap /proc/meminfo # Shows swap information.
```

As always with linux, there are plenty of ways doing it and this gives the requested information in some form. You can adjust the switches to modify this or probably use different methods to get the same information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what statistics you want exactly but here are some commands you can use:

- top is an interactive command, it's very similar to the task manager in windows but as a cli program, it lists processes with their CPU% and MEM% usage in real time along with other useful statistics.

  `top`
- for RAM usage you can use

  `free -h`
- for disk space usage

  `df -h`
- to calculate certain directory disk space you can use

  `du -h <path>`
- to view CPU load averages in the last 1,5,15 minutes you can use

  `uptime`
- to list running processes

  `ps all`
- For detailed CPU info

  `cat /proc/cpuinfo`
- For detailed memory info

  `cat /proc/meminfo`